# rewriteengine and direct combine with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i have a coded script which show url like `example.com/pagename` .

i want to use rewriteengine to show it like `example.com/page=pagename` 
and redirect `example.com/pagename` to `example.com/` to hide script typecode .

can you help me please ?

is it possible to change ``completely to another thing like `page=` ?
this is what exactly i am trying to do.

i already tried some codes like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\=([^/]*)$ /$1 [L]
```

it shows `example.com/page=pagename` correctly but you can load `example.com/pagename` and `example.com/page=pagenamepagename`

Comment: Why not instead have your URLs structured: `example.com/pagename`? `example.com/page=pagename` doesn't really seem like an improvement over the original?

Comment: i need it for a purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but you can load `example.com/?a=pagename`

To prevent this you also need an external redirect to your desired URL (before your internal rewrite). In order to prevent a rewrite loop, you can check against `THE_REQUEST`:

```
# Redirect typed URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /page=%1? [R,L]
```

The trailing `?` on the substitution removes the original query string. (Once you are happy with the redirect, change it to a permanent redirect, `R=301`.)

> but you can load ... `example.com/page=pagename?a=pagename`

Well, this is expected. However `page=pagename` will take priority and `?a=pagename` will be stripped by your rewrite. However, to reject such requests. ie. Only rewrite when there is no query string then modify your existing rule with a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^page=([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

This will result in such URLs triggering a 404.

---

**UPDATE#1:** To handle requests for `example.com/pagename`, instead of `example.com/page=pagename`:

```
# Redirect "ugly" URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R,L]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL to the real URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE#2:** A stricter version of the above. This only allows "pagename" to consist of the characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, `_` and `-`:

```
# Redirect "ugly" URLs to the desired URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R,L]

# Internally rewrite the "pretty" URL to the real URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you repat above command for example.com/pagename ? thanks alot

Comment: come back @w3d pleaseeee

Comment: I've updated my answer for `example.com/pagename` requests - it's not really much different. I've just noticed... you don't need to escape the `=` in the `RewriteRule` pattern (regex) - it carries no special meaning.

Comment: Unless `example.com/pagename` is actually a valid request, then this should trigger a 404 - the same as the first method. Try clearing browser cache etc.

Comment: i use another device and i can load it ! but thank you for your help ,. you are the best . any other suggestion ?

Comment: A request such as that one should not be processed at all by the directives above, which is why it should fall through to a 404. It won't be redirected because the URL-path ("pagename") is not empty and it won't be internally rewritten because the query string is not empty. Any typos? Maybe you can paste your actual .htaccess file into your question?

Comment: And that is all the code you have in your .htaccess file?

Comment: yes . i am new here sorry for more and more editing . i add it to first post . it is all i have in my .htaccess . nothing more .

Comment: Presumably you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: yes . i tested it . and the first metod are working .

Comment: Just try emptying/renaming (or commenting out) your entire .htaccess file and then try your request again for `example.com/pagename?a=pagename`. What happens?

Comment: it says Not Found 404

Comment: Well, the regex could be tightened to reject invalid characters... What characters can the "pagename" consist of? Just the lowercase letters a-z? Or uppercase as well? Numbers? At the moment it includes _everything_ (including `?`) apart from a slash.

Comment: Without an .htaccess file at all then a request for `example.com/?a=page1?a=page2` will result in your script receiving the value `page1?a=page2` for the `a` variable - it is then up to your script to validate this.  But this is different to `example.com/page1?a=page2`.

Comment: you mean it is because of the script ?? i should know that .

Comment: Well, if you have removed the .htaccess file and `example.com/?a=page1?a=page2` loads page1 then your script is interpreting `page1?a=page2` as page1. I'll update my answer with a "stricter" version.

Comment: done . i find out what is happening here . i fixed it thanks

Comment: wow thank you for updates . i will use them and say what happens .

Comment: the 2nd update is work fine . so this means i owe you :) you are best . i am new here and it is best new user first day in the world :)

Comment: Cool, glad it's working! What did you have to "fix"?

Comment: is there any way to add & to above characters ?because some features like example.com/page&says=success not work .

Comment: `example.com/page&says=success` is not actually a valid URL, I assume you mean `example.com/page?says=success`? ie. you need to allow for an additional query string on the URL? A problem with this is that you wanted to reject the request (serve a 404) when `a=page` was supplied in the URL (eg. `example.com/page?a=page`). Is this still a requirement? TBH, I wouldn't reject the request in this instance - I would just make sure it was ignored. `w+&=-` - it's not quite so simple as changing the pattern.